# Restricting access to public Cloud Run endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run

I'm running a backend app with several endpoints on Cloud Run(fully-managed). My endpoints are publicly available by its nature so I don't want to authenticate users through my client app hosted on Netlify.

What I do need is to restrict access to my endpoints so that other applications or malicious users can't abuse it. It is not about scaling, I just don't want to exceed the [Free Tier limits](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits) since it is a demo of an opensource application.

I've already set the [concurrency](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#concurrency_values) and [max instance](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits) limits to minimum but this alone is not enough. There is also a product named [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor) but it seems an expensive one, not free.

I was expecting to have a simple built-in solution for this but couldn't find it.

What other solutions do I have? How can I block the traffic coming out of my website on Netlify?

Comment: How do you want to restrict the access? Use a private IP (and thus a VPN to access to Cloud Run)? allow only a subset of public IP to access to your service?

Comment: Something like that yes. I want to block the traffic coming out of my website on Netlify.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a lot of solution:

- You don't want to authenticate your users -> so you need to rely on the technical layers
- Netlify is a serverless hosting platform, you don't manage servers/IPs -> So you need to rely on the host name

To filter on the host name, you can use 2 products

- External HTTPS only (about $15 per month) with url path matching.

  - Default URL land on a dummy service
  - Only request where the host matches your netlify host name are redirected to your backend
- Use Cloud Armor on top of External HTTPS load balancer ($15 + Cloud Armor policy x traffic volume). The time, the load balancer redirect the default URL to the correct backend and Cloud Armor check the request origin.

The problem is that this weak solution is easy to overpass. Perform a simple curl with the host as header, and HTTPS Load Balancer and Cloud Armor think that is the correct origin

```
curl -H 'Host: myNetlifyHost.com' ....
```

The highest protection is the authentication. Google Cloud itself say: "Don't trust the network".

Comment: Thanks for the options. It is sad to see no free options available. But even if I implement authentication for my endpoints, there will be a public URL (ex: /login) for generating tokens, etc. which then will possibly be exposed to a brute-force attack and consume cloud resources right? That's why I thought that a network layer security(IP/host restriction) is needed.

Comment: No if you rely on the Google authentication method (Firebase auth or Google Account).